# Syntax help - adding attachments to slack incoming webhooks

Tags: curl, slack-api

I'm writing up a slack integration and I'm trying to add a message attachment but I'm stuck on the syntax of putting it all together into a curl statement.

This is the basic curl statement that I have right now that I want to add an attachment to:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
--data "{\"text\":\"$MESSAGE\"}" \
https://hooks.slack.com/services/code1/code2/code3
```

Below is the example given of an attachment:

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": false
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I'm confused on how to place that attachment block inside the curl statement. Could someone write up a complete curl statement that would include that attachment block for me so I can see how it's done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its actually pretty easy. `attachments` is just another key in your JSON array, on the same level as `text`.

So your new JSON array should look something like this (obv. before character escaping):

```
{
  "text": "here goes your message text",
   "attachments": 
   [
      {

         "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

Btw. you can add other keys like `channel` and `icon_url` the same way.